# wxPython: Create a log system

Tags: logging, wxpython

I have an application that calls another script when clicking on a button. On that script, I have some prints that I would like to display on a wx.TextCtrl widget on the application but I have no clue where to start.

This is an example of the script called:

```
#export.py

def exportData():
    #some code
    #Some prints that I would like to display on the application
```

And here is how I call the script from the application:

```
def loadData(self, event):
    from export import exportData
    exportData()
```

I have some questions:

1. I assume that print won't work as a log, and I have to use some kind of logging system. Is that correct? I've tried to use log.write but I keep getting "log not defined error".
2. Maybe calling exportData() directly from def loadData isn't the best way to proceed. If it's the case, what is the correct way?
3. Finally, How can I display the prints/logs into the wx.TextCtrl widget of the application?

Don't hesitate if you need more information. Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Here is a minimalist working example code of what I'm trying to do. Printing "This is my log" in the main.py TextCtrl.

```
# main.py
import wx, sys
import export

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Frame aka Window", size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)

        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Export", pos=(80, 80), size=(120, 30))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.export, button)

        mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mySizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
        mySizer.Add(log, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(mySizer)


    def export(self, event):
        from export import exportData
        exportData()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Test(parent=None, id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

and the export file:

```
#export.py

def exportData():
    print("This is my log")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, congratulations on engineering the following statement `import export`, it makes me smile each time I see it.
Are you attempting something like this?

[image]

Here is your amended code to do that:

```
# main.py
import wx, sys
from export import exportData

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Frame aka Window", size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY, size=(180,100))
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Export")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.export, button)
        mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mySizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
        mySizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(mySizer)

    def export(self, event):
        exportData(parent=self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Test(parent=None, id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

and the `export.py`

```
import time
import wx

def exportData(parent=None):
    if not parent:
        return
    log = []
    print("This is my log")
    parent.log.write("This is my log\n")
    #solely for the purpose of illustrating updates in real time use sleep between updates
    # and yield to the gui main loop
    # in real time operation remove the sleep commands
    wx.Yield()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Log line 2")
    parent.log.write("Log line 2\n")
    wx.Yield()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Log line 3")
    parent.log.write("Log line 3\n")
    wx.Yield()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Export data has concluded")
```

All that is happening here is we pass the `parent` to the function, which allows the updates to occur in real-time. The call to `Yield` passes control momentarily back to the `wx.App.MainLoop` for the update to be seen occurring, otherwise, although the update occurred, the result isn't seen, until the `MainLoop` takes back control.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is the closest to what I want as a result. But, my only problem is that the log is added when the function finishes, and I want it to be real-time, that's what a log is meant to be :) the only solution I see is to use SQLite db, If you have a better solution don't hesitate,

Comment: You omitted that detail in your question. One way is to pass the `parent` to the function and perform the updates from within the function. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works great on a script I have, but weirdly, it doesn't work for the same script usnig multithreading. It seems that the script stops working after 2 or 3 iterations. Do you have any idea what it could be? Thank you again

Comment: Multi-threading is a different kettle of fish. All updates have to occur within the wx `MainLoop`, so you will have to use something like `pubsub` to fire off events in the thread/s which will be caught by the `MainLoop` where the update has to occur.

Comment: I started laughing when I saw import export. Have some + votes from here, both of you.

Comment: @Juha Still chuckling 4 years later! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "Log" as an TextCtrl.

```
self.log = wx.TextCtrl(Panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
```

If you want to add something your could write it like this:

```
self.log.AppendText('Your String here')
```

To clear it you do it like this:

```
self.log.Clear()
```

To be more detailed we need to see more of your code. But maybe this will help you already.

Also i would import on top of your Module not inside a function.

```
from export import exportData

def loadData(self, event):        
        exportData(yourLogData)
```

I dont know where the information for you log are coming from but i would assume you need to pass it to exportData like this:

```
[...]
self.log = wx.TextCtrl(Panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
[...]
def exportData(self, yourLogData):
    #some code
    #Some prints that I would like to display on the application
    self.log.AppendText(yourLogData)
```

Comment: Sorry for being late but I had to do some tests and unfortunately I'm missing something because it doesn't work for me :( I've edited my initial question with a minimalist example so you can see what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your help. It's appreciated.